# Getting data is fast, but Flash displaying php data is slow, why?

Tags: php, mysql, flash

In my database(mysql), I have a table which has 50k data(rows/records).

I do a test using firebug, after playing the game, the call to load_score.php and save_score.php is around 380ms (millisecond).

The save_score.php just a normal inserting, nothing much. The load_score.php, I use this query:

```
SELECT name, score
FROM `highscores`
WHERE id =1
LIMIT 0, 10
```

- The result returns 10 rows
- the query returns in 0.0005 seconds (tested using phpmyadmin)
- I echoed the data back to flash.

But on my game (flash), it tooks 11 seconds(count manually) to load and save the score. Why the time differences is so big?

Could it be the problem when Flash received php data, the process to display is slow??

Are there any others reasons on why the displaying take longer time??

(If you need more information, please let me know)

Firebug Testing Result:

```
================================================================
=       File       |   firebug time   |   actual/on web time   =
================================================================
=   load_score.php |      435 ms      | 5 seconds(before it calls save_score.php)
=   save_score.php |      643 ms      | 4-5 seconds(before displaying highscore table)
================================================================
```

So the total time to display the highscore = ~10 seconds

Comment: It is barley hard to say something when we do not know in which format you send the data and how you process it in the flash movie. Usually flash uses the same http connections as the browser does.

Comment: You mean send from flash - php - flash?? Its in "variables" format

Comment: try to use firebug + firefox to see how much time is lost in sending and reciving data and the rest of the is lost in displaying the information.

Comment: Look in the Net panel right? I will put the details in the "edit" section in my question.

Comment: Could it be the problem when Flash received php data, the process to display is slow??      -> Yes . did you try to run only the flassh on the client side ( with hard coded data ) ?

Are there any others reasons on why the displaying take longer time??    --> many things , the proper way to find bottle necks is to travel the same way your data does from the server to the client messuring every step of the way . With the results you have i would guess this has to do with the way flash retreives the data , what do you use to to transfer data from php to flash ?

Comment: I havent tested with hardcode data. "what do you use to to transfer data from php to flash ?" Umm, I use URL variables. Is that what you are asking??

Comment: To properly diagnose the problem you should for starters time the request in flash itself. take a timestamp just before the request starts, do that again just after, and again just after loading the table with it's data, and review these values. Then you will see how fast you get the data into flash, which i suspect should be about the same figures as you see in firebug. And how much time is taken by processing + displaying the data. If all that is as it's supposed to be, maybe the time is lost before, so extend your measurements there.

Answer (score 0):

Not 'the' answer, but you might save up to 5 seconds by combining both requests into one. Have the save script also return the high score table. You will at least save half a second (transfer time reported by firebug) and maybe more if there's a delay in flash for some reason.

The comments above should point you in the right direction in solving or at least identifying the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use [amfphp library](http://www.amfphp.org/) and thus send/receive data in Flash native AMF format which Flash can fast way faster.